# Toolbar shadow issue on Android lollipop 5.0

Tags: java, android, background, toolbar

I was doing final touches on my app and noticed strange behavior on my toolbar on devices running 5.0 and above. On devices that are below 5.0 there is no strange line below my image which I setup as a `backgroundDrawable`for toolbar but on devices 5.0 and above seems like toolbar is visible behind the image. I tried many approaches that I found mostly here on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. I tried with `transparent` background but that didn't work. I created custom theme with also with `transparent` background but that didn't work too. Here are the images:
[image: Bellow Lollipop]
[image: Lollipop and above]

Code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_final"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />
     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hate when get down vote without explanation!! If you know something please guide me and mark the question as duplicate if it really is but provide explanation. Seems down voting should be rare privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to remove shadow from toolbar:

```
 <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Also set  `app:elevation="0dp"` in `AppBarLayout` for hiding shadow in `appbar`

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the shadow feature of Toolbar.. so hide it..

Try..applying `"app:elevation="0dp"`  in the "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Thumbs up for your comment too.